# Correct CDF for W=XY?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have two random variables with joint PDF:

I have the joint density for two random variables $X$ and $Y$:

$$
p(x,y) = \begin{cases}
            \frac{6}{5}(x+y^2) & \quad \textrm{if}{\ } 0 < x < 1,{\ } 0 < y < 1\\
            0 & \quad \textrm{otherwise}
         \end{cases}
$$

And I want to find the CDF for $W=XY$, which I call $H(w)$. My idea is that for $w\leq0$ we have $H(w)=0$ and for $w\geq1$ we have $H(w)=1$. For $w \in (0,1)$ I get:

$$H(w)=\int_{\mathbf{R^2}}1_{xy\leq{}w}p(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \frac{6}{5} \int_{x=0}^w \int_{y=0}^1 x+y^2 \, dy \, dx + \frac{6}{5} \int_{x=w}^1 \int_{y=0}^{w/x}x+y^2 \, dy \, dx$$

Calculating the integrals I get $H(w)=\frac{w}{5}(9-3w-w^2)$, which makes sense to me in the way that $H(w)\in(0,1)$ and $H(0)=0$ and $H(1)=1$.

But is this correct or have I missed something?

Comment: The integrals are set up correctly, I didn't confirm the calculation.  However your checks suggest that it's all OK, and you can also check that$$H'(w)=\frac95-\frac65w-\frac35w^2=\frac35(4-(w+1)^2)$$which is non-negative for $0\le w\le1$, so $H$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! I makes good sense!